# How to render audio analyser in 3D webgl space

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I'm trying to make an audio analyser. I made a start with it using the 2D context of HTML canvas and it already looks very good.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Audio Analyser</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
        }
        canvas {
            position: fixed;
            left:0;
            top:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <audio src="track/life to take.wav" id="audio-master"></audio>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio-master");
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var actx = null, ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"), analyser, source;
        window.onload = drawPlayButton;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        window.onclick = function () {
            if (audio.paused) {
                if (actx == null) {
                    actx = new AudioContext();
                    analyser = actx.createAnalyser();
                    source = actx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
                }
                var spectrum = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
                var peekSpectrum = new Float32Array(64);
                var peekVelocities = new Float32Array(64);
                source.connect(analyser);
                analyser.connect(actx.destination);
                analyser.fftSize = 2048;
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                function render() {
                    if (!audio.paused) {
                        requestAnimationFrame(render);
                    } else {
                        drawPlayButton();
                        return;
                    }
                    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(spectrum);
                    var bandamount = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
                    var bandwidth = canvas.width / 64;
                    var bottom = canvas.height;
                    for(let i=0;i<64;i++) {
                        let j = toLog(i*bandamount/64+1, 1, bandamount);
                        let k = spectrum[Math.floor(j)], l = spectrum[Math.ceil(j)];
                        let m = k + (l - k) * (j%1);
                        if (isNaN(l)) m = k;
                        let n = Math.pow(m, 3+i/128) * bottom / 0x4000000;
                        if (n >= peekSpectrum[i]) {
                            peekVelocities[i] = (peekSpectrum[i]-n)/10;
                            peekSpectrum[i] = n;
                        } else {
                            peekSpectrum[i] -= (peekVelocities[i]+=bottom/1000);
                        }
                        let o = peekSpectrum[i] + 16;
                        let grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,bottom);
                        grad.addColorStop(0,"#0000ff");
                        grad.addColorStop(0.3,"#6600ff");
                        grad.addColorStop(1-m/1000,"#ff00ff");
                        grad.addColorStop(1,new Color(255, m, 255, 1.0));
                        ctx.fillStyle = grad;
                        drawBand(bandwidth*i+4, bottom-n, bandwidth*(i+1)-4, bottom, 8);
                        drawPeek(bandwidth*i+4, bottom-o, bandwidth-8, 8);
                    }
                }
                // Logarithmic formula by Gerard Abello
                function toLog(value, min, max) {
                    var exp = (value-min) / (max-min);
                    return min * Math.pow(max/min, exp);
                }
                function drawBand(x1, y1, x2, y2, r) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(x1, y2);
                    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1+r);
                    ctx.arcTo(x1, y1, x1+r, y1, r);
                    ctx.lineTo(x2-r, y1);
                    ctx.arcTo(x2, y1, x2, y1+r, r);
                    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                }
                function drawPeek(x, y, w, r) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x+r, y, r, Math.PI*0.5, Math.PI*1.5);
                    ctx.lineTo(x+w-r, y-r);
                    ctx.arcTo(x+w, y-r, x+w, y, r);
                    ctx.arcTo(x+w, y+r, x+w-r, y+r, r);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                }
                audio.play();
                render();
            } else {
                audio.pause();
                audio.currentTime = 0;
            }
        }
        function drawPlayButton() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 80, 0, Math.PI*2);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#404040C0";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(canvas.width/2-40, canvas.height/2-40);
            ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/2-40, canvas.height/2+40);
            ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/2+40, canvas.height/2);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffffc0";
            ctx.fill();
        }
        function Color(red, green, blue, alpha) {
            this.red = red & 255;
            this.green = green & 255;
            this.blue = blue & 255;
            this.alpha = arguments.length > 3 ? alpha : 1;
            this.toString = function() {
                if (this.alpha === 1) {
                    return (0x1000000 | this.red << 16 | this.green << 8 | this.blue).toString(16).replace(/^1/,"#");
                } else {
                    return (0x100000000 + this.red * 0x1000000 + this.green * 0x10000 + this.blue * 256 + this.alpha * 255 & 255).toString(16).replace(/^1/,"#");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Audio Analyser]

However, I want to make it 3D. I want to make a hallway with the analyser rendered on the walls. So I need to convert this whole thing into WebGL. And I don't know where to start. And as you can see, the analyser also has some curved lines as well. I know you cannot draw curved lines in WebGL, but there should be a way around it.

Comment: I would suggest using a library to handle the webgl stuff. May I suggest [Three.js](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene)? It has a great/large community, which makes it relatively easy to get started with. But if 3d is new to you, this is generally a VERY, VERY hard task you've thrown yourself over.

Comment: I am aware that using libraries can make my life easier. But I want to learn how it exactly works and I want it to be optimised. That is why I like to do stuff on my own way. The problem is not the WebGL language itself. It is just figuring out how to render this whole thing onto multiple surfaces and with those curved lines.

Comment: Quick update. I've managed to make it work, but the bad news is that the lines are straight. Second bad news, I don't know how to copy and paste the rendered thing inside other parts of the context

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was overcomplicating it completely. All I had to do is make another canvas, because a canvas is also considered a validated texture in WebGL. The first canvas is hidden and draws the spectrum using the 2D context, the second canvas copies the whole content of the first one and pastes it inside a WebGL context. I can very easily make multiple of these, and I don't have to worry about curved lines. If I knew it is gonna be that easy, I wouldn't have asked this question.